# Минимальная площадь прямоугольника

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия, теория

**Задача**:

Есть множество точек на площади. Их координаты заранее известны.

- Надо построить вокруг них прямоугольник минимальной площади.
- Прямоугольник можно крутить.

Вариант с построением прямоугольника по экстремальным точкам, и последующее вращение с попыткой упаковать все точки внутри мне не понравился изначально.

Интуитивно пришел к выводу, что площадь будет минимальной в том случае, если хотя бы 2 точки будут лежать на одной из сторон прямоугольника.

А теперь вопрос:

В какую сторону копать, чтобы доказать, что данный прямоугольник - минимальный?

Кроме численных методов в сравнении с другими алгоритмами (например, алгоритмом поворота - тут все понятно - результаты в сравнении с этим алгоритмом на уровне погрешности).

Comment: "Интуитивно пришел" - интуиция подвела. Может быть, все-таки заняться математикой?

Comment: Хорошо, почему данная площадь не минимальна и в каком случае она будет минимальной? Математически? Хотя бы численно, в каком случае?

Comment: Интуиция вполне себе верна. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box_algorithms. Алгоритм простой: строим выпуклую оболочку (алгоритм найдёте в сети), перебираем все стороны получившегося многоугольника и строим прямоугольник.  Находим минимальный

Comment: Метод rotating calipers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) применяется при решении и этой задачи.

Comment: *площадь будет минимальной в том случае, если хотя бы 2 точки будут лежать на одной из сторон прямоугольника* Не так. Если на одной стороне лежит не менее 2 точек, а на остальных - не менее 1 точки. После построения выпуклой оболочки (и отбрасывания из рассмотрения всех внутренних точек) останется "хотя бы на одной стороне лежит строго 2 точки, а на остальных - 1 или 2 точки".